# EF Core, Join table "uploads" and retrieve all "groups" with more than X uploads

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In my case I want to retrieve a list with all groups where the total amount of uploads by their users exceeds or is equal to X value.

```
A briefly example:

Group A, 5 Users, 3 Uploads
Group B, 2 Users, 10 Uploads
Group C, 6 Users, 5 Uploads
and I want all groups with more or equal than 6 Uploads
```

So in this case List<Groups> should only contain Group B.

**The models:** (Note; in this case a user is only able to be in one group)

```
public class Users
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public ......
    .............
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
    public virtual Groups Group { get; set; }
}

public class Groups
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual Categories Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Uploads
{
    public int UploadId { get; set; }
    public int UploadedByUserId { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("UploadedByUserId")]
    public virtual Users User { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime CreatedUTC { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

I'm currently able to retrieve all groups without a single upload by saying:

```
List<Groups> groups= await _db.Groups
                .GroupJoin(_db.Uploads, g => g.GroupId, u => u.User.GroupId, (g, u) => new { g, u })
                .SelectMany(x => x.u.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, u) => new { x.g, u })
                .Where(x => x.u == null)
                .Select(x => x.g)
                .ToListAsync();
```

but I'm currently struggeling saying something like:

```
.where(u => u.Count() >= X-VALUE)
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: If you need to call Join, your EF model is probably wrong.  All relationships should be declared in your models.

Comment: Show models not *short*, but classes with navigation properties.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv models have been added/updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your navigation properties should go both way

- Your users have a group so your groups should have a collection of users
- your uploads have a user so your users should have a collection of uploads

With those properties added it becomes as simple as

```
List<Groups> groups= await _db.Groups
    .Where(g=>g.Users.SelectMany(user=>user.Uploads).Count() >6)
```

Comment: +1, although I'd probably skip SelectMany altogether: `_db.Groups
    .Where(g=>g.Users.Sum(user=>user.Uploads.Count()) >6)`

Comment: This works like a charm. The reason why I started to use join is because even my earlier attempts with something similar resulted in an error. But yea, this error actually makes sense now that you are mentioning “navigation properties should go both way” & “…have a collection of users & …. a collection of upload”. Adding these made the trick.

Comment: @PierreKnudsen yes, you need to think of it from non SQL terms just as a graph you navigate, so if you want to query both ways, you need navigation both ways. The best way to think in LINQ is to avoid thinking in SQL, while you may need it once in a while it's best to assume that if you're using the word join in an operator you have a model issue or a query writing issue as those should almost always be abstracted away while writing the query naturally even if they get translated to joins by the EF profider.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```cs
var groups = await _db.Groups
    .Where(grp => _db.Uploads.Count(up => up.User.GroupId == grp.GroupId) >= X)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This one also works like a charm, even without the need to add additional navigation properties for both ways (In code first).